# Spring boot All request Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Even adding `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();` all request are unauthorized.

This is my **WebSecurityConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)   
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Is there something im missing?

**Edit**: I've also added this config in the application.properties

`security.basic.enable: false
security.ignored=/**`

Answer (score 0):

Configuration class looks fine. Make sure to **"build"** your project before running it. I replicated your configuration file and it worked for me.